# angular charts set data based x,y position

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

i'm following this tutorial [angular-charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for implements charts

but how to set my data based (x,y) value on $scope.data?

i'm stack, please help me

Answer (score 0):

For bar chart you may try as below:

```
<canvas id="locationBar" class="chart chart-bar" data="chartParams.votes" labels="chartParams.listOfLocations" series="chartParams.series" colours="chartParams.colours" options="chartParams.options"></canvas>
```

With the following angular code (in a controller of course)

```
$scope.chartParams = {
    listOfLocations: ['Trenzalore','Earth','Caprica','Sol','Tau Ceti'],
    votes: [[5,10,6,7,2]],
    series: ["Nice Places"],
    colours: [{fillColor:getRandomColour()}],
    options: {barShowStroke : false}
};
```

You can change values of `data` as per your requirement.

Go [Here](https://lingohub.com/blogs/2014/06/comparison-angularjs-directives-charts-front-end-app-development/) for more